# The best way to have a pointer to several methods - critique requested

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I'm starting with a short introduction of what I know from the C language:

- a pointer is a type that stores an adress or a NULL
- the `*` operator reads the left value of the variable on its right and use this value as address and reads the value of the variable at that address
- the `&` operator generate a pointer to the variable on its right

So I was thinking that in C++ the pointers can work this way too, but I was wrong. To generate a pointer to a static method I have to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
    static void dummy(void){ std::cout << "I'm dummy" << std::endl; };
};

int main(){
    void (*p)();
    p = Foo::dummy; // step 1
    p();
    p = &(Foo::dummy); // step 2
    p();
    p = Foo; // step 3
    p->dummy();
    return(0);
}
```

Now I have several questions:

- Why does step 1 work?
- Why does step 2 work too? Looks like a "pointer to pointer" for p to me, very different from step 1.
- Why is step 3 the only one that doesn't work, and is the only one that makes some sort of sense to me, honestly?
- How can I write an array of pointers or a pointer to pointers structure to store methods (static or non-static from real objects)?
- What is the best syntax and coding style for generating a pointer to a method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what is the best syntax and coding style for generating a pointer to a
>   method?

Don't. Use `std::function<void()>`.

Now, on to the steps. Step 1 is technically illegal, but your compiler allowed it by implicitly taking the address for you. Step 2 is how it should be done. The name of a static function (in this case, `Foo::dummy`) is a function *lvalue* and must have it's address taken to be legal C++ and yield a function pointer.

Step 3 simply doesn't make any sense at all. You're trying to assign ... a run-time function pointer ... to a type? That makes no sense whatsoever. And then you try to access ... a member ... of a function pointer? Does not compute.

There are two parts to the answer "What do I do when I want to X in C++?". The first part, for C veterans only, is "Forget whatever you think you learned in C". The second part is about doing X.

> how can i write an array of pointers or a pointer to pointers
>   structure to store methods ( static or non-static from real objects )

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> arr;
```

le done.

Comment: Function to function-pointer conversion is a standard conversion (including for _static_ member functions) (§4.3), I'm pretty sure step 1 is entirely valid (and identical to step 2 in semantics).

Comment: @Mat: That's what I thought. Otherwise, C++ would break C backwards compatibility for no good reason.

Answer (score -1):

> what is the best syntax and coding style for generating a pointer to a method?

According to [C++ Faq lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/)'s paragraph about "[Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5)", in general you should use a typedef to create the pointer, and a macro when calling the member function (points 33.5 and 33.6 respectively).
This makes it simpler to call the method on a given object.

In your example you are using a static method, so you don't need an object to call it.
However here is what your code would look like following these recommendations, when calling a non static member function :

```
// define the macro to use pointer to methods
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))

class Foo{
    public:
    void dummy1(void){ std::cout << "I'm dummy 1" << std::endl; };
    void dummy2(void){ std::cout << "I'm dummy 2" << std::endl; };
};

int main(){
    // define the PointerToFooMember type. Note that you can use it for dummy1 and dummy2 as well
    typedef void(Foo::*PointerToFooMember)();
    PointerToFooMember ptr = &Foo::dummy1;

    // create an object to call the method later
    Foo foo;

    // call the method
    CALL_MEMBER_FN(foo, ptr)();
}
```

Comment: -1 for needless macro and poor use of Standard facilities. L2 `std::bind`.

Comment: In some environments (embedded for example), you sometimes have less access to the std functions (including std::bind), so the macro version could be helpful to some people.   However I would be very interested if you could provide us a version of the above code sample rewritten using std::bind.

Comment: Should be roughly like `std::bind(ptr, foo)`. Maybe a `std::ref` in there if you want to refer to `foo` instead of copy. As for embedded, it makes up *barely over* 1% of the software industry. It's not applicable to general-case answers. If you don't specify limitations on the Standard library in the question, they do not exist. Oh, and the macro could be replaced with a template, not to mention that it's *less verbose without*, so even if you don't have `std::bind` it's very poor.